# Java blueJ class Member / Lan

Tags: java

```
public class Member 
{

    private String name;
    private String alias;
    public int balance;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Member
     */
    public Member(String fullName, String nickname)
    {
        this.name = fullName;
        this.alias = nickname;
        this.balance = 0;
    }
    public void setBalance(int account)
    {
        if(account > 0)
        {
            balance = balance + account;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You have not entered a valid number");
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Lan
{
    private ArrayList<Member> members;

    public Lan()
    {
      members = new ArrayList<Member>();
    }

    public void addMember(Member newMember)
    {
        if(balance >= 200)
        {
            this.members.add(newMember);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You dont have enough money to enter");
        }

    }
}
```

In the `Member` class, I got a balance, where you put in the balance of the member "money", and in the `Lan` class, I want it to be that you can enter the Lan "add member to the array" IF the member have balance = 200. I'm not able to make the balance field act as it should and importing it into the `Lan` class.

Comment: Shouldn't `if(balance >= 200)` be `if (newMember.balance >= 200)`?

Comment: Thank you very much Tom, it worked! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's check the `addMember` method:

```
public void addMember(Member newMember)
{
    if(balance >= 200)
    {
        this.members.add(newMember);
    }
    //...
}
```

Here you're trying to decide if the `newMember` should be added to the list `members`. The problem is that `balance` cannot be resolved, because there is no such variable in the `Lan` class or in the `addMember` method.

This can be easily fixed, because you're trying to access the field stored in the `newMember` object, so you can change

```
if (balance >= 200)
```

to

```
if (newMember.balance >= 200)
```

That way you directly access the value of the `balance` field in the `newMember` object.

Note that this access is only possible, because the access modifier of that field is `public`. If it were `private`, like for the other fields, you would need a getter method like:

```
public int getBalance()
{
    return belance;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
if (newMember.getBalance() >= 200)
```

Since it is always a good idea to use [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28computer_programming%29), it is better to set this field to `private` and use a getter.

Comment: This is really helpful man ! ive changed it to private and done it this way now. Now if i were to print out who is on the Lan, all members who is registered, do i need to use a interator ? and how would i do this? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: If that answer helped you, then don't forget to [accpet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it. To print your list just override the `toString` method in `Member` (there are a lot of example on the internet ;)) and then call `System.out.println(members)`.